# habilitar y deshabilitar campos

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy terminando un proyecto y quisiera ver la forma de habilitar y deshabilitar un campo de texto dependiendo del radiobutton que seleccione el usuario.

ya encontré un código en el foro y es lo que quiero solo que mi cuestionario se llena de un array que me trae las preguntas de una base de datos y esto ocasiona que al seleccionar un "no" me habilite todos los campos y yo solo quiero que habilite el campo de texto de la pregunta donde el usuario puso que "no".

este es mi formulario

```html
<?php 
            //consulta que captura el texto , id de la tabla respuestas 
            $sql = "SELECT texto,id FROM respuestas WHERE idenc='$id'"; 
            $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); 
            //ahora recorremos los datos texto, id que estan vinculadas a la cuenta seleccionada 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                $texto = $row["texto"]; 
                $idres = $row["id"];   
            ?><tr> 
              <!--  <td width="50"><input type="radio" name="opcion" value="<?php echo $idres; ?>" required</td> 
                <td width="470"><?php echo $texto; ?></td>--> 
            <?php echo "<fieldset>  
                  <legend>".$texto."</legend>  
                  <label>  
                    <input type='radio' name='radio".$idres."' value='1' onclick='deshabilita()'> Si  
                  </label>  
                  <label>  
                      <input type='radio' name='radio".$idres."' value='0' onclick='habilita()'> No  
                  </label>  
                  <label>  
                      <textarea name='Hallazgo".$idres."' disabled class='inputText'>Se tiene un hallazgo? </textarea> 
                  </label> 
                 <label>  
                      <textarea name='Accion".$idres."' disabled class='inputText'>Cual es la acción correctiva </textarea> 
                  </label>  
            </fieldset>"; ?>     
            </tr> 
            <?php } ?> 
            <tr>
```

este es el codigo javascript

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
    function habilita(){
        elementos=document.getElementsByClassName("inputText");
        for(var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++)
        {
            elementos[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
 
    function deshabilita(){
        elementos=document.getElementsByClassName("inputText");
        for(var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++)
        {
            elementos[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema actual es que estás seleccionando todos los `.inputText` sin discriminar de ninguna manera, por lo que te activará/desactivará todos de golpe.

Una posible solución pasaría por  aprovechar que el `name` del `.inputText` va a tener una parte en común con el radio button (el id que viene de PHP `$idres`). Entonces en lugar de seleccionar todos los `.inputText` lo que harías es seleccionar sólo los que tengan un `name` con el mismo id que el radio que se pulsó.

Esto lo puedes hacer sustituyendo esta línea:

```
elementos=document.getElementsByClassName("inputText");
```

Por estas dos (comentadas):

```
// nos quedamos con el idres
var id = event.target.name.replace("radio","");
// seleccionamos sólo el Accion y Hallazgo con ese idres
elementos = document.querySelectorAll(".inputText[name=Accion"+id+"], .inputText[name=Hallazgo"+id+"]");
```

Opcionalmente, para evitar algún posible error de compatibilidad con navegadores antiguos, podrías pasar el idres como parámetro a `habilita`/`deshabilita` o usar algún data-atributo o similar para ello.

El resultado lo puedes ver funcionando aquí:

```js
function habilita() {
  var id = event.target.name.replace("radio","");
  elementos = document.querySelectorAll(".inputText[name=Accion"+id+"], .inputText[name=Hallazgo"+id+"]");
  for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].disabled = false;
  }
}

function deshabilita() {
  var id = event.target.name.replace("radio","");
  elementos = document.querySelectorAll(".inputText[name=Accion"+id+"], .inputText[name=Hallazgo"+id+"]");
  for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>texto 1</legend>
  <label>  
    <input type='radio' name='radio1' value='1' onclick='deshabilita()'> Si  
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type='radio' name='radio1' value='0' onclick='habilita()'> No  
  </label>
  <label>  
      <textarea name='Hallazgo1' disabled class='inputText'>Se tiene un hallazgo? </textarea> 
  </label>
  <label>  
    <textarea name='Accion1' disabled class='inputText'>Cual es la acción correctiva </textarea> 
  </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>texto 1</legend>
  <label>  
    <input type='radio' name='radio2' value='1' onclick='deshabilita()'> Si  
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type='radio' name='radio2' value='0' onclick='habilita()'> No  
  </label>
  <label>  
      <textarea name='Hallazgo2' disabled class='inputText'>Se tiene un hallazgo? </textarea> 
  </label>
  <label>  
    <textarea name='Accion2' disabled class='inputText'>Cual es la acción correctiva </textarea> 
  </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>texto 3</legend>
  <label>  
    <input type='radio' name='radio3' value='1' onclick='deshabilita()'> Si  
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type='radio' name='radio3' value='0' onclick='habilita()'> No  
  </label>
  <label>  
      <textarea name='Hallazgo3' disabled class='inputText'>Se tiene un hallazgo? </textarea> 
  </label>
  <label>  
    <textarea name='Accion3' disabled class='inputText'>Cual es la acción correctiva </textarea> 
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: solo que tengo una cuestion cuando paso el formulario a guardar a mi BD me aparcese este error Notice: Undefined index: Hallazgo21 como si el campo no existiera

Comment: Eso ocurre porque los campos que están des habilitados no se envían con el formulario. Debes comprobar que estén rellenos (con `isset`) antes de guardarlos en la base de datos.

Comment: ok tengo algo asi --- if(isset($_POST['Accion'.$id_preg])){echo "no-vacio";}else{ $Accion = "";}
    if(isset($_POST['Hallazgo'.$id_preg])){echo "no-vacio";}else{ $Hallasgo = "";}  ---  pero me sigue marcando el erro Notice: Undefined index: si guarda en la bd pero no quiero que salga ese erro

Comment: ¿Y cómo haces el insert?

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$id_preg= $row[0]; 
resp= $_POST ['radio'.$id_preg]; 
$Accion = $_POST['Accion'.$id_preg];
$Hallasgo = $_POST['Hallazgo'.$id_preg];
if(isset($_POST['Accion'.$id_preg])){echo "no-vacio";}else{ $Accion = "";}
if(isset($_POST['Hallazgo'.$id_preg])){echo "no-vacio";}else{ $Hallasgo = "";}
$consulta = "INSERT INTO opciones (idenc, id_pregunta, valor, Accion, hallazgo, fecha, hora) VALUES ('$id' ,'$id_preg' ,'$resp' ,'$Accion' ,'$Hallasgo' ,$fecha_actual ,'$Hora')"; 
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

Comment: parece que ya esta resuelto no se si es correcto ya que soy nuevo en php .---while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){$id_preg= $row[0]; $resp= $_POST ['radio'.$id_preg]; if (isset($_POST['Accion'.$id_preg])) {$Accion = $_POST['Accion'.$id_preg];}  else{ $Accion = "" ;}if (isset($_POST['Hallazgo'.$id_preg])) {$Hallasgo =$_POST['Hallazgo'.$id_preg];}else{ $Hallasgo = ""; }  $consulta = "INSERT INTO opciones (idenc, id_pregunta, valor, Accion, hallazgo, fecha, hora) VALUES ('$id' ,'$id_preg' ,'$resp' ,'$Accion' ,'$Hallasgo' ,$fecha_actual,'$Hora')";$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

Comment: @antoniosanchez parece que ya debería funcionar, porque ahora sí se comprueba si el valor existe en el `$_POST` antes de leerlo. Como comentario aparte, deberías leer sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código que tienes puede ser vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.